# Sorting a JSON objects' child-keys by their child-keys' values

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, sorting

I am looking for a way to sort my three main JSON keys (`neutral`, `positive`, `negative`) using their children `y`-keys' values.

This is how the JSON object is set up:

```
{
  "chartSeries" : {
    "negative" : [ {
          "y" : 1505,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/1"
        }, {
          "y" : 425,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/2"
        }, {
          "y" : 1046,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/3"
    } ],
    "neutral" : [ {
          "y" : 10,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/4"
        }, {
          "y" : 1,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/5"
        }, {
          "y" : 2,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/6"
    } ],
    "positive" : [ {
          "y" : 230,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/7"
        }, {
          "y" : 50,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/8"
        }, {
          "y" : 483,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/9"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Let's say I want to sort the `negative` values descending by `y`'s value, then my JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "chartSeries" : {
    "negative" : [ {
          "y" : 1505,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/1"
        }, {
          "y" : 1046,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/3"
        }, {
          "y" : 425,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/2"
    } ],
    "neutral" : [ {
          "y" : 10,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/4"
        }, {
          "y" : 2,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/6"
        }, {
          "y" : 1,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/5"
    } ],
    "positive" : [ {
          "y" : 230,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/7"
        }, {
          "y" : 483,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/9"
        }, {
          "y" : 50,
          "url" : "http://www.test.com/8"
    } ]
  }
}
```

*note how the negative elements are ordered by their descending y-values and neutrals' and postives' values are ordered exactly in the same sequence.*

I tried parsing it as Javascript object using `JSON.parse()` and then using a sort function:

```
function sortResults(data, prop, asc) {
    sorted_data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
        else return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
    });
    return sorted_data;
}
```

But I just get "TypeError: data.sort is not a function" in my debugger.

Any explanations or advices are kindly appreciated!

Comment: `sort()` is a method in [Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Following up on @Teemu's comment, see [the MDN for a reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), `JSON.parse()` returns an Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll stick with JSON.sortify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json.sortify) as it perfectly suits my needs.

The code behind that magical function:

```
function sortKeys(o) {
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        return o.map(sortKeys)
    } else if (o instanceof Object) {
        var _ret = function() {
            var numeric = [];
            var nonNumeric = [];
            Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
                if (/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/.test(key)) {
                    numeric.push(+key)
                } else {
                    nonNumeric.push(key)
                }
            });
            return {
                v: numeric.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a - b
                }).concat(nonNumeric.sort()).reduce(function(result, key) {
                    result[key] = sortKeys(o[key]);
                    return result
                }, {})
            }
        }();
        if (typeof _ret === "object") return _ret.v
    }
    return o
};
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

And do not forget to add a paseInt() to ensure all the keys are integers. I had somy funny time figuring that back in the days.